# Why I can't retrieve data from my webserver as json but i can when i test it on localhost

Tags: android, json, android-volley

I'm trying to create a simple login app that connects to mysql database.
The app works find when i test it in localhost , but when i uploaded the database and the php scripts to a Hosting server ( Byethost ) it is not working, 
the problem seems with the response string form the server, it is not "JSON"

as i mentioned above, when i test the application in localhost it works just fine.

## here is the Andorid Code

```
        requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
    StringRequest stringRequest = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, login_url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try{
                Log.d("#-SERVER RESPONSE-#",response);
                JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(response);
                Log.d("#-LOGIN STATUS-#",jsonObject.getString("status"));
            } catch (Exception e){
                Log.d("#-JSON ERROR-#",e.toString());
            }//end if
        }
    },
            new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("#-VOLLEY ERROR-#",error.toString());
                }
            }){

        @Override
        public Map<String,String> getParams(){
            Map<String,String> params = new HashMap<>();
            params.put(KEY_USERNAME,username);
            params.put(KEY_PASSWORD,password);
            return params;
        }
    };
    requestQueue.add(stringRequest);
```

## And here is the php code

```
    $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['username']);
$password = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['password']);

$query = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE username='{$username}' AND password='{$password}'";
$result = mysqli_query($connection,$query);

$json_reply['status'] = 1; //erorr by default

if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
  $json_reply['status'] = 0; //success
}

print(json_encode($json_reply));
```

## Here is what the output of the Android Monitor window.

[image]

## Response string

```
<html><body><script type="text/javascript" src="/aes.js" ></script><script>function toNumbers(d){var e=[];d.replace(/(..)/g,function(d){e.push(parseInt(d,16))});return e}function toHex(){for(var d=[],d=1==arguments.length&&arguments[0].constructor==Array?arguments[0]:arguments,e="",f=0;f<d.length;f++)e+=(16>d[f]?"0":"")+d[f].toString(16);return e.toLowerCase()}var a=toNumbers("f655ba9d09a112d4968c63579db590b4"),b=toNumbers("98344c2eee86c3994890592585b49f80"),c=toNumbers("99efa97c59e1cf6146f7e801802ed6bc");document.cookie="__test="+toHex(slowAES.decrypt(c,2,a,b))+"; expires=Thu, 31-Dec-37 23:55:55 GMT; path=/"; document.cookie="referrer="+escape(document.referrer); location.href="http://zsoft.byethost8.com/login.php?ckattempt=1";</script><noscript>This site requires Javascript to work, please enable Javascript in your browser or use a browser with Javascript support</noscript></body></html>
```

Comment: show your code for executing web service

Comment: Can you post the complete response string from the server? It looks like a normal HTML Site.

Comment: @Mono actually it is so weird, i will update the question with the response string

Comment: Where you pass user name and password in your volley request at android code ?

Comment: @Vickyexpert i pass them as two parameters (username,password) i just posted the body of the function. i'm wondering why it is working fine in my localhost

Comment: It seems like either you are calling wrong API from app or may be parameter not set to request and there for it is not able to execute your API, So pls check once your login_url and data.

Comment: @Vickyexpert thanks i will check them again, but how do you explain the fact it is working in my machine. i was thinking that the problem with the hosting, something like ( you can't retrieve pure json for security purposes )

Comment: @ZakariaJawas for that you need to provide login_url then I can exactly tell you what is the reason of api not call, it may be possible one reason should be hosting

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114349/discussion-between-zakaria-jawas-and-vickyexpert).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems the problem was with the hosting itself, I tried another hosting (arvixe) and everything works as charm. i have no idea why but maybe because it is a payed hosting.

Comment: Maybe is some security config. on the server, your requisition method is POST ?

Comment: Yep , im using POST request, i tried GET too i even tried to echo a json string without hope

Comment: I see, Get request may be blocked due to special chatacter in url what is blocked in some servers, Post don't have this problem i think

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem a while ago, I do not know why but I managed to solve using `echo json_encode ( $ response , JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE ) ;` instead of`print` and escaping special characters in encode instead of mysqli , hope it helps

Comment: Maybe apache is blocking special characters , the return contains any? If so, try to harcode the response without special characters to test.

Comment: I tried that, i start believing it is something related to the Content-tpye i tried application-json but it keeps returning text-html

Answer (score 0):

Many of the free hosting provider are appending the analytics code at the end, that is the major reason why php files fails.

The best solution for this type of problem is to use

```
 <?php exit(); ?>
```

after the last executable statement, which will explicitly close the PHP file.

When you exit explicitly PHP file, the code will not be appended to the JSON.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i would give that a try and i will let you know what happened

Comment: I tried your answer but nothing happened, same problem