# Volley onResponse android not work

Tags: java, android, android-volley, jsonresponse

**MainActivity:**

```
RequestQueue requestQueue;
String url = "http://andriodtest.eb2a.com/show.php";
TextView textView;
ListView listView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    textView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView);

requestQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET, url,
        new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, response.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                try {
                    JSONArray jsonArray = response.getJSONArray("users");
                    for (int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject respons = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                        String id = respons.getString("id");
                        String info = respons.getString("name");
                        textView.append(id);
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

            }

        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
    @Override
    public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
        Log.e("VOLLEY", "ERROR");
    }
}

);
requestQueue.add(jsonObjectRequest);
```

When run app no data called
And file config is work 100%.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmJaL.png)

And if set Textview= "text" not work.

I think the problem is   public void onResponse.
Please help me important

Comment: Your PHP backend is not giving JSON but a raw HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Your code seems fine, however it looks like your server's response is not returning a json object but instead a javascript file for setting a cookie (you can try hitting your url with Postman to look at the javascript response I'm mentioning).

Volley expects to receive a json response and that may be the reason why your app is currently not working as expected.

I would probably try to change the way the server responds. The following link has some suggestions in order to solve that issue: 
[Why I can't retrieve data from my webserver as json but i can when i test it on localhost](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37746956/why-i-cant-retrieve-data-from-my-webserver-as-json-but-i-can-when-i-test-it-on)